# How to read the excel file from the request body in aws lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, multipartform-data, fastapi

I am getting the excel file in the request body, but when I try to read through `openpyxl` or `xlrd`, it is raising the error.

The FastAPI endpoint:

```py
def upload_file(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    
    for part in decoder.MultipartDecoder(request.get("body").encode('utf-8'), request.get("headers").get("Content-Type")).parts:
        content = part.text
        file_open = pd.read_excel(content.encode('utf-8'), engine='xlrd')
        pc_sheet_names = file_open.sheet_names
```

The error:

```
 File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1361, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("Bad magic number for central directory")
```

Comment: How big is your file ?

Comment: What if you saved the file locally before?

Comment: i try to save the file and read back again its giving error Not valid file [Errno 22] Invalid

Comment: I am getting the data and after encoding the body of request its  like :  b'----------------------------758679477641211471359369\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="ssn-121212121.xlsx"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n\r\nPK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x

Comment: Where do you save the file, in /tmp folder?

Comment: i have tried two ways, i) directly reading from the body of request by encoding 2)and i stored to /tmp/some_file.xlsx and read both given the same issue. As my understanding we need to do some way to remove the content of file ----------------------------758679477641211471359369\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="ssn-121212121.xlsx"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet\r\n\r\n , but not getting how to do

Comment: @saraswathimoram Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048825/how-to-upload-file-using-fastapi/70657621#70657621) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) on how to upload files in FastAPI. You don't have to read the raw request body, and even if you did, you could always use `request.form()` to parse the body, which would get you a `FormData` object that you can use to get the `File` and/or `Form` data (see Option 1 of  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804) for more details).

Comment: Hi Chris, I was tried this way , but in aws lambda UploadFile is not working, its giving the lambdaContext object, and same way request coming as dictionary and it does'nt have the form

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61660586/17865804).

Comment: I have added the APIGway configuration as well as mentioned in the above ticket, and still facing the same issue, file is  coming into request.get("body") with boundary and form-data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74348340/17865804 this is not duplicate @chris, both are different scenario's, any one way if able read the file, also fine for me.